# where to look in meteor app if vue-router suddenly stops sending props to other vue compoents

Tags: meteor, vuejs2, vue-router

everything was working just fine and suddenly now Vue components are not receiving the props sent on router-view.

I've tried deleting the 'local' and .cache folders and running

> meteor

again but still the other Vue components don't get the props (undefined).

I've tried to build some previous commits of my repo but everywhere the props are not being sent now.

in a neighboring directory, another meteor-vuejs-vuerouter proj is still working perfectly with similar routing.

I've changed browsers, tried terminal instead of iterm2, etc.

In Vue tools, I can see App.vue getting the data from subscription and computed properties are generated. but then in the child Vue component, the props show as 'undefined'.

Any ideas on where in the build process of meteor or any other place that vue-router could be causing this problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you update the Meteor release for this project or any vue related package? When you restored the older commits did you make sure to reinstall npm packages?

Comment: thank you! yes, ive compared .meteor files like release n versions, also compared package.json .. when i tried older commits, i did a git clone in a clean directory (n then did npm install)

Comment: so i found it! even when my package.json file had  "vue-router": "^3.0.0",    in both projects, in the project where the router was misbehaving i found the vue-router 2.0 version instead of 3.0 .. i manually deleted the older version n copied the newer folder into node_modules and it now works!

Comment: Please answer your question so it's clear for everyone that it's answered

Answer (score 0):

even when my package.json file had "vue-router": "^3.0.0", in both projects, in the project where the router was misbehaving i found the vue-router 2.0 version instead of 3.0 ..i don't know how it crept in..someone suggested package-lock.json is useful but for now i manually deleted the older version n copied the newer folder into node_modules and it now works!